# Multiple TextViews with one Picker

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I can't seem to get my two `UITextView`s working with my `UIPickerView` correctly with Swift.

I tried using tags to differentiate between my TextViews but my second TextView will not update correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var homeTeamNameTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var awayTeamNameTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var teamNamesPicker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

    // Array of teams
    let teamNamesArray = ["Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Hull City", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "Queens Park Rangers", "Southampton", "Stoke City", "Sunderland", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur", "West Bromwich Albion", "West Ham United"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        teamNamesPicker.hidden = true;
        teamNamesPicker.delegate = self
        homeTeamNameTextView.text = teamNamesArray[0]
        homeTeamNameTextView.delegate = self
        awayTeamNameTextView.text = teamNamesArray[1]
        awayTeamNameTextView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return teamNamesArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return teamNamesArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if homeTeamNameTextView.tag == 0 {
            homeTeamNameTextView.text = teamNamesArray[row]
            teamNamesPicker.hidden = true;
        } else if awayTeamNameTextView.tag == 1 {
            awayTeamNameTextView.text = teamNamesArray[row]
            teamNamesPicker.hidden = true;
        }
        return
    }

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool{
        teamNamesPicker.hidden = false
        return false
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this property to your class:

   ```
   var activeTextView: UITextView?
   ```
2. In `textViewShouldBeginEditing` set `activeTextView`:

   ```
   func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool{
       teamNamesPicker.hidden = false
       activeTextView = textView
       return false
   }
   ```
3. In `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` use `activeTextView` to update the right text view:

   ```
   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       activeTextView?.text = teamNamesArray[row]
       teamNamesPicker.hidden = true
       return
   }
   ```

Comment: That was awesome "vacawama". Thank you.

If I have a really long teamNamesArray how to execute this with two columns in picker. 

For example top level is league names like EPL, LFP, Bundesliga etc and teams in each league in the other column?  


// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 2
    }

Comment: The array I have is still longer but it is something like this: 

 let teamNamesArray = ["[ EPL LEAGUE NAME]", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Burnley","Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Hull City", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "etc"  "[ LFP LEAGUE NAME ]", "Almería", "Athletic Bilbao", "Atlético Madrid", "Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Real Sociedad", "Sevilla", "Valencia", "Villarreal", "[ BUNDESLIGA ]", "Augsburg", "Bayer Leverkusen", "Bayern München", "Borussia Dortmund", "etc"] 

 Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post this as a new question.

Comment: I added it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639282/swift-uipickerview-hierarchy-levels

I will try and work it out from the Objective-C example but if you think you can help with a swift solution that would be great.

Thanks again for your previous answer.