# UIPickerView hierarchy levels

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I am would be greatful for some help in getting a **swift** solution of something 'similar' to this code which was done in Objective-C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493402/show-data-in-uipickerview-second-component-based-on-first-component-selection).

I basically want a picker with two components. I would like to be able to select a row in first component and on that basis of selected component in one column it shows the value of the corresponding data in the second. This would stop the endless scroll when searching for a specific football club.

Data:

```
Top Level: 
leagueName.text
Second Level: 
teamName.text
```

Relevant code looks like this:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTeamNameTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var awayTeamNameTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamNamesPicker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    var activeTextView: UITextView?
    // Array of teams (a bit large needs to fix... [ EPL ] is not a teamName but leagueName followed by leagueNames)
    let teamNamesArray = ["[ EPL ]", "Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Burnley","Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Hull City", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "Queens Park Rangers", "Southampton", "Stoke City", "Sunderland", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur", "West Bromwich Albion", "West Ham United", "[ LFP ]", "Almería", "Athletic Bilbao", "Atlético Madrid", "Barcelona", "Celta de Vigo", "Córdoba", "Deportivo La Coruña", "Eibar", "Elche", "Espanyol", "Getafe", "Granada", "Levante", "Málaga", "Rayo Vallecano", "Real Madrid", "Real Sociedad", "Sevilla", "Valencia", "Villarreal", "[ BUNDESLIGA ]", "Augsburg", "Bayer Leverkusen", "Bayern München", "Borussia Dortmund", "Borussia M'gladbach", "Eintracht Frankfurt", "Freiburg", "Hamburger SV", "Hannover", "Hertha BSC", "Hoffenheim", "Mainz", "Paderborn", "Schalke", "Stuttgart", "Werder Bremen", "Wolfsburg", "[ SERIE A ]", "Atalanta", "Cagliari", "Cesena", "Chievo", "Empoli", "Fiorentina", "Genoa", "Hellas Verona", "Internazionale", "Juventus", "Lazio", "Milan", "Napoli", "Palermo", "Parma", "Roma", "Sampdoria", "Sassuolo", "Torino", "Udinese", "[ LIGUE 1 ]", "Bastia", "Bordeaux", "Caen", "Évian", "Guingamp", "Lens", "Lille", "Lorient", "Lyon", "Marseille", "Metz", "Monaco", "Montpellier", "Nantes", "Nice", "Paris Saint-Germain", "Reims", "Rennes", "Saint-Étienne", "Toulouse", "[ A-LEAGUE ]", "Adelaide United", "Brisbane Roar", "Central Coast Mariners", "Melbourne City", "Melbourne Victory", "Newcastle Jets", "Perth Glory", "Sydney FC", "Wellington Phoenix", "Western Sydney Wanderers"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        teamNamesPicker.hidden = true;
        teamNamesPicker.delegate = self
        homeTeamNameTextView.text = "Select Home Team"
        homeTeamNameTextView.delegate = self
        awayTeamNameTextView.text = "Select Away Team"
        awayTeamNameTextView.delegate = self
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // returns the number of 'columns' to display.
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return teamNamesArray.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return teamNamesArray[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        activeTextView?.text = teamNamesArray[row]
        teamNamesBackground.hidden = true
        teamNamesPicker.hidden = true
        return
    }

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool{
        teamNamesBackground.hidden = false
        teamNamesPicker.hidden = false
        activeTextView = textView
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really try implementing something on your own first... But the secret will lie in making your `titleForRow` and `numberOfRowsInComponent` delegate methods return values based on conditionals.

Comment: Lindsey, To be honest I found the Objective-C solution when writing the question. I will have a crack by going through it but had such an amazing experience with my first question (instantly answered) and my app is already working that I got excited and wanted to reduce the user inefficiencies of my app. I will also look into updating some values from server by fetching plists and dictionaries. A little excited and a touch impatient :)

Comment: Geeeeee not that easy... still battling... to implement the Objective-C code in Swift.

Comment: If you post what you have so far, I can take a look.

Comment: Was failing with Swift so I went back to Objective-C but I have errors: "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning "NSUinteger" (aka 'unsigned long') etc...
 
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0)
    {
        return [selection count];
    }
    else {
        if ([team isEqualToString:@"EPL"]) {
            return [epl count];
        }
        // if...
        else  {
            return [epl count];
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}

Comment: So the above code isn't actually your current code...